# Two div tags sidy by side

Tags: html, css

Hello maybe this has been asked in the passed but I want a really more clear idea of how this work when you need to place two DIVS side by side. can you show it with html and css as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried before asking for explanation!!!

Comment: Go work through some tutorials that explain the basics of layouting via CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` to do this.

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/8d39f73c91753891d6e1)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

---

If you don't want a whitespace separating these two `div`s change your HTML to:

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/0de7979adc36bc352b23)

```
<div id="left"></div><div id="right"></div>
```

---

If you want each `div` to take up 50% to the full width, change the `width` of both `div`s to `50%`:

### [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/4f2faf965d4bb1720ec7)

```
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
#right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```